# Make an image power of 2

Tags: java, android, sprite

Do I need to make every image power of 2(Android) for better performance?
For example how could I make this: http://starbounder.org/mediawiki/images/1/18/Pixel_Hero_Set.png
picture po2 without stretching it?
My problem was that I wanted to keep the aspect ratio, and by stretching it to po2 it won't keep the aspect ratio. So to keep the aspect ratio and make it po2 I need to add transparent space to the image(in this case on the left and on the right handside) and I wanted to know if this decreases the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use a photo editor such as [pixlr](https://pixlr.com/express/)
2. Import the image (Open URL: http://starbounder.org/mediawiki/images/1/18/Pixel_Hero_Set.png)
3. Click "Adjustment"
4. Click "Resize"
5. Change to a power of 2 such as "32" for width (Keep proportion, the width/height ratio works out such that the height is in a power of two as well)
6. Save the new image

Otherwise, if you are in charge of the art, just make it in power of two to start with.

Comment: Okay this worked, but what about sprites with different proportions so if you change the width to 32 the height won't be po2?

Comment: "if you are in charge of the art, just make it in power of two to start with". Or you can just take the minor performance hit. If the answer worked for your question, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Would there be performance hit if there is white space left in the image?

Comment: You can refer to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982074/libgdx-opengl-2-0-and-textures-having-to-be-powers-of-two)